# How to sort values in columns and update table?

Tags: sql

I'm completely new to sql and can't do that myself. So I need your help.
I want to sort values in column and then save changes. But I don't know how to do that.

Table looks like that:

```
Id | Name | SomeDescription
---------------------------
1  |Best  | Description1
2  |Worth | Description2
3  |Good  | Description3
```

I want to get something like that:

```
Id | Name | SomeDescription
---------------------------
1  |Best  | Description1
2  |Good  | Description3
3  |Worth | Description2
```

So I need to sort "id" and "name" columns.

I use following statement to sort values of "name" column:

```
SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY name ASC
```

But how can I sort the values of id column and save changes in table?
Please, help.

Comment: You don't change data when you sort generally, data tables are never guarnateed to return data in a particular order.

Comment: Why would you want to save database tables sorted?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester It's a long history. In brief I need that for my application.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to effectively sort database tables without saving the sorted ones as a copy or using a very complex or series of update statement(s). Your best bet is to write a **stored procedure** or save the query that sorts the table. That way you just have to execute that to get the sorted table. You won't muck up your database that way. I can still see the value of _reading_ it sorted, but saving it sorted makes no sense. So what I'm saying is you should "save the sorted read".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You would have to use a second table

1. create a new table `games2` with the same structure as your `games` table, making sure the ID is auto-incrementing

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `games2` LIKE `games`;
   ```
2. copy the data, sorted, into `games2`

   ```
   INSERT INTO `games2` (`Name`, `SomeDescription`) SELECT `Name`, `SomeDescription` FROM `games` ORDER BY `Name`
   ```
3. drop or move the old table

   ```
   -- DROP TABLE `games`;
   -- or
   RENAME TABLE `games` TO `games1`;
   ```
4. rename new table to old name

   ```
   RENAME TABLE `games2` TO `games`;
   ```

These steps will result in what you want.

Comment: @Sabre & Umbrella Table implemenaton/storage has order but a table is an unordered abstraction. The only way to ever get order in a query is an outermost ORDER BY.

Comment: How is this so upvoted?  If the table has an autogenerated PK then this code probably replaces the original table with one in which the PK order (initially) is consistent with ordering by the `Name` column, but SQL has no sense of sorting a table itself, only sorting *results*.

Comment: It answers the question precisely.  The problem you describe is with the question, where the asker is trying to do something we generally don't do -- reorder rows on the disk.  I can't think of a use case for that, because we all just use `ORDER BY` on our result sets, but, that's apparently what the question was, and this is how you do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER ranking function to renumber the rows.

```
SELECT UnsortedId = id
, SortedId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY g.name, g.id)
FROM games
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use alter table command which is simpler.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE games ORDER BY name asc;
```

That's all !

Comment: Maybe this works in mysql, but definitely not t-sql. Would be pretty convenient!

Answer (score 0):

you can sort on two fields at the same time.

```
SELECT *
FROM games
ORDER BY id DESC, name ASC
```

I don't understand what you mean by save changes in the table.  The `ORDER BY`, is just changing the display that you are looking at it doesn't change the data in the table unless you perform an `UPDATE`.

If you are unfamiliar with SQL, there are a lot of tutorials online that can help:

[SQL Course](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html)

[Beginner SQL Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm)

[SQL Tutorial - Learn SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/)

Edit based on the comments, this can be done in one step:

```
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    name varchar(50),
    somedesc varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values (1, 'best', 'desc1')
insert into #temp values (2, 'worth', 'desc2')
insert into #temp values (3, 'good', 'desc3')

update t1
SET t1.id = t2.rn
    , t1.somedesc = t1.somedesc
FROM #temp t1
JOIN 
(
    select id, name, somedesc, row_number() over(order by name, id) as rn
    from #temp 
) t2
on t1.id = t2.id

select *
from #temp
order by id

drop table #temp
```

Comment: What you're saying is correct, of course, but notice what he wants done in his example - the `Id` column stays the same.

Comment: @cha0site you are right. When I sort two fields in that way I got no changes in table

Comment: @cha0site you are right, i misunderstood the OP. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

it is simple. just use a few codes. I have tried this and it is working. first create a temporary table while sorting values at the same time.

```
    create table new as select * from games order by name;
```

and then drop the games table using,

```
    drop table games;
```

now create games table again with same properties and data as in new (where sorting here is an optional) using,

```
    create table games as select * from new order by name;
```

now drop the temp table 'new'

```
    drop table new;
```

now check your table. it must be sorted out.

Comment: I don't get, what the second create / drop is for, just renaming `new` to `games` would be enough. And you will loose a lot of your table schema (constraints, defaults, triggers, ...) when using this method! And I can't see the difference to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fix... stupid simple:

1. Extract to temp table

SELECT SortKeyValue *(add any other fixed values, just don't include the existing sequence)* INTO #Temp FROM SourceTable;

2. Empty the table:

TRUNCATE TABLE SourceTable

3. Reinsert:

INSERT INTO SourceTable (SortKeyValue, DisplayOrder *(plus other fields)*)
SELECT SortKeyValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortKeyValue) AS DispOrd 
*(plus other fields)* FROM #Temp;

4. Done!

Answer (score -3):

SQL> SELECT * FROM games
     ORDER BY ID,NAME;

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?