# SQL - UPDATE TABLE and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, sql-order-by

So I have an unordered table `movement` that has columns `timestamp`,`x`,and `y`. I want to order by `timestamp`, and change and save the table to have the all rows ordered by timestamp.

I wanted to use `UPDATE TABLE` but I'm unsure on how the query would look... for example, I have this:

```
UPDATE movement 
SET ????? 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

I don't want to set anything, I just want to change the order of the table. I need to do this for another query that I'm going to write, but the fact is that this table is very large and I need to break up things in steps so that the performance isn't terrible later. So how would I do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table) SO post that addressed a similar question, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it rather than use another table, because as I said, this table is very large(millions of rows) and recopying the table would take a long time.

Comment: Although it doesn't make much sense to "order" a table this way, you could create a dummy table to store the values in the sorted order. Then delete the content of the original table and copy everything back, adding an additional column named `sortorder` which you populate with rownum during the update. But the question is, why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Would there be any reason to use UPDATE tablename, could you just create a new ordered table, and replace the old table?

Comment: What you could also do is create a `view` instead, containing an SQL query ordering by timestamp. Then you can reference this view as if it were a table.

Comment: @avk  thanks, I might end up doing that. I want to do this because I have another query that I want to implement on the table that would go much faster with an ordered table since it would check for all `timestamp >= 'example timestamp'`. Or is that logic not true?

Comment: Yes and no. A view is nothing more than an easy way to simulate a table based on business-logic. So it will query this view instead of treating it as a table. What you could look into is something called `materialized views` which actually create dummy tables. Unfortunately this has it's own drawbacks like the refreshing interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables don't inherently have an order; you don't have to update them into any particular order.

What you do is choose the order of what you SELECT from the table. Then it can be in any order you choose!

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM movement  
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

But then somewhere else maybe you want to:

```
SELECT * FROM movement  
ORDER BY timestamp DESCENDING;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ORDER BY` in `UPDATE` statement. `ORDER BY` should be used with `SELECT` statement only. Again, there is no need of having the records stored in particular order cause you can just display the records in particular order with a `SELECT statement` like

```
select * from movement 
order by timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Relational database tables represent unordered sets. There is no syntax for sorting a table, simply because there is no such concept as the order of rows in a table. When you issue a query without an explicit `order by` clause, the database may return the rows to you in any order it may see fit, which might be influenced by the order they were inserted and written to disk, their presence in some memory cache, indexes, or a host of other implementation details.

If you want to query the table's rows sorted by their timestamp, just explicitly state it in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     `movement`
ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible. This is in MySQL format... Update is for editing already existing information.  If you want to make more direct changes, use ALTER or MODIFY according to syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE movement 
ORDER BY timestamp;
```