# SqlBulkCopy is not inserting rows in same order from the .net DataTable to Sql table in Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
objDataTable=ConversionClass.ConvertToDataTable(strFilePath,"tbl_transactonData", ",");       String strConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnectionString);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_AllTransactiondata";
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            bulkCopy.Close();
        }
```

I need to transfer value from datatable to Sql Table using SqlBulkCopy.
But SqlBulkCopy is not inserting rows in proper order .Please suggest solution for the same.

Comment: How did you determine that the results are in the wrong order? Why does it matter what order they're inserted, as long as all the target data makes it in? There's a fundamental misunderstanding about ordering within SQL tables here, I think.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName,,,, i am transferring value from excel to datatable and then to sql Table,,,,,Since these are transaction data order is important here..  when i looked in Datatable order is correct but after sqlbulkcopy order is not correct in the Sql Table,,,

Comment: @LaxminarayanCharan That doesn't answer Esoteric's question: "HOW do yo know that the data is not in the correct order". You could only know that if there was a field in the original data, such as a TransactionDate, and then possibly an IDENTITY value in the SQL Server table, and order by one is not the same result as ordering by the other. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is no guaranteed order for bulk insert operations. Besides inserting each row individually (neither fun nor efficient), you might could try using the `TableLock` [SqlBulkCopyOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions.aspx).

```sql
new SqlBulkCopy(strConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
```

It will attempt a minimally-logged operation which can only be done via an ordered insert, which will be done via a background sort in `tempdb` first.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the order by clause in sql. Of course this assumes that your data is already sorted by one column.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You could create a new table that is a sorted version of the old table after you have completed all of the inserts. Again, same assumption.
[How to sort values in columns and update table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table)

You could insert one row at a time with a foreach loop. You would also need to create a DataRow[] of one row each time.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac44f8yy(v=vs.110).aspx

The ideal solution in my mind is either using the order by clause or sorting it after all of the insertions. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to guarantee it would insert rows sequentially.

Class description:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx