# Sorting order column of button click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table as city which stores the information of entered city. In city table i've one columns name as city_order which stores the order of city to display (1,2,3...etc). When listing the order, i've up and down arrow in the table. When user clicks on up arrow of any city, i've to change the order of that city as well as the city above it. I am calling ajax function on the click of the arrow and getting the order of the clicked city. If up arrow is clicked then i am chaging the order of the previous city to current order and vice versa. If down arrow is clicked i am chaging the order of the next city to current order and vice versa. This thing is not working as expected. Please find below ajax code.

```
$cityid = $_REQUEST["cityid"];
$cityorder = $_REQUEST["cityorder"];
$type = $_REQUEST["type"];
if(isset($type) && $type == "up"){
    $newcityorder = $_REQUEST["cityorder"] - 1;
}else{
    $newcityorder = $_REQUEST["cityorder"] + 1;
}
$productid = $_SESSION["productid"];
$dclass1->query("update tbl_city set city_order = '$cityorder' where city_order = '$newcityorder' AND item_id = '$productid'");
$dclass1->query("update tbl_city set city_order = '$newcityorder' where cityid = '$cityid'");
```

Comment: when you want to show the sorted data to user you don't have to update your table,  You have to do it at front end for that user only .. google sort table by jquery or javascript.

Comment: Try using datatables https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. @MehravishTemkar. I know data tables but it is not my solution here. AND @M A SIDDIQUI i want to update the table also because its not just for display purpose. The sorting of field in database is also important

Comment: You want to update the table and not just do an order by query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table maybe this might help

Comment: i am using order by only while displaying. For example i've 5 cities as order from 1 to 5. Now when i am clicking on 3rd city up button then 3rd city order should be changed to 2 and 2nd city order should be changed to 3

Comment: try to use concept of sortable plugin in jquery.

Comment: Guys please understand my question first and then post your reply. I cant use any plugin here. I've to update the table also.