# Trigger to sort and update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this, `Id` is the primary key, so obviously the tables is ordered by Id.

```
+----+----------+--------+
| Id |  OrderNo |  Col2  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        3 | Value3 |
|  2 |        1 | Value1 |
|  3 |        2 | Value2 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

What I want to do is to reorder the table after every new insert by `OrderNo`, as follows:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| Id |  OrderNo |  Col2  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  2 |        1 | Value1 |
|  3 |        2 | Value2 |
|  1 |        3 | Value3 |
|  4 |        4 | Value4 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Is this possible? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079750/how-to-sort-values-in-columns-and-update-table), It says to drop and re-create the table. Is there anyway that i can do it with one go?

As a matter of fact I tried to execute the first query in the accepted answer but SSMS gives me an error.

[image]

Comment: Make `OrderId` primary key and the table will be ordered automatically.

Comment: The table data usualy doesn't follow any particular order as it doesn't matter anyway.
You should use ORDER BY clause in your SELECT query to get the order you need.

Comment: Reordering of the table itself is a wrong requirment. You don't care how the database internaly stores the data. Use ORDER BY in your SELECT query. This will give you what you need everytime.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the automatic reordering by primary key and order by another column?

Comment: Ordering has nothing to do with if there is a primary key or an index or not. I frequently have tables where rows are entered in a certain order, they have a primary key in that same order, but if I go "Select * from table" with no ORDER BY clause they will come out in a different way. You're wasting your time trying to implement this, because SQL will ignore it if it feels like it anyway.

Comment: A table in a RDBMS is an inherently **unordered** bag of data - even with `Id` as your primary key, it's **NOT** ordered by that key! There's no point and no benefit in constantly "reordering" the table - you're only wasting your resources. The **ONLY** way to get ordering in a RDBMS is by `SELECT`ing from the table and specifying an **explicit** `ORDER BY`

Answer (score -1):

Use a view to have the data sorted in any manner you like independent of what has been input.

Comment: Nope - as Marc said, a table has no inherent order. A view is effectively a virtual table and you cannot sort a view. If order of rows matters, the query that generates a resultset must **MUST** include an order by clause. The only way you can use an order by clause in a view is if you use the top directive. For that to be generically useful, you must use "top 100 percent" - which the optimizer ignores.